# How to share local IP within a cluster if server is bound to one IP?

Tags: mysql, haproxy, keepalived, galera

I have a cluster with 3 nodes running in VMs on test setup. Now I want to take it to production and rented 3 dedicated root servers at Hetzner Online connected by a switch.

As I found out, they do not offer anymore shared IP and instead bind a server to one IP. That is no problem for external IPs as they offer an alternative with failover IP.

However my DB-Servers are adressed through the internal adress 10.0.0.10 which leads 2 keepalived HAProxy servers that spreads the load. I do not want to use an external IP for this.

How do I keep the traffic internal and in the same time use HAProxy with failover if I can not configure shared IPs?

The point where it failes is:

```
sudo sysctl -p
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip nonlocal_bind: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The config you're after is called `ip_nonlocal_bind`. The failure you've posted mentions `ip nonlocal_bind`, so it's missing a `_`. So, check your config for this typo. If there are more problems you're running into, please edit your question stating exactly what is happening, what should happen, and provide configs etc.