# DNS issue with Failover IP from Hetzner

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, high-availability, failover, hetzner

Assume we have two servers A and B with 'real' and external IPs and we can switch the so called ['failover ip'](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Failover/en) (W.X.Y.Z) to point to a specific external IP of A or B. This works from the 'outside' and was easily done. 
As a background: the failover ip is configured as a new entry in /etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto eth0:0  
iface eth0:0 inet static
  address W.X.Y.Z
  netmask 255.255.255.224
```

Now let us assume W.X.Y.Z is configured dynamically to use hardware A. Now I call 'curl domain.com' from B and it uses the correct failover ip W.X.Y.Z but then resolves somehow to the wrong external IP B (or localhost?) instead of using the configured one A:

```
Trying W.X.Y.Z ...
* connect to W.X.Y.Z port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to domain.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to domain.com port 443: Connection refused
```

When I start the local nginx it can successfully curl domain.com

**Do I need to configure DNS locally somehow? How can I find out more about the DNS chain?**

Using [mtr](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_mtr.htm) just prints domain.com if trying this from server B

Is this related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/721249/how-to-share-local-ip-within-a-cluster-if-server-is-bound-to-one-ip)?

```
The failover IP is W.X.Y.Z and is also the A record of domain.com

The /etc/hosts file for both nodes serverA and serverB looks like:

    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.1.1       luminarhost            
    xxx    serverA
    xxx    serverB        

The /etc/network/interfaces of serverA

    ### Hetzner Online AG - installimage
    # Loopback device:
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    # device: eth0
    auto  eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
      address   xxx
      broadcast xxx
      netmask   xxx
      gateway   xxx
      # default route to access subnet
      up route add -net xxx netmask 255.255.255.224 gw xxx eth0

    iface eth0 inet6 static
      address xxx
      netmask xxx
      gateway xxx

    # failover ip
    auto eth0:0
    iface eth0:0 inet static
      address W.X.Y.Z
      netmask 255.255.255.224

and of serverB it is:

    ### Hetzner Online AG - installimage
    # Loopback device:
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    # device: eth0
    auto  eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
      address   xxx
      broadcast xxx
      netmask   xxx
      gateway   xxx
      # default route to access subnet
      up route add -net xxx netmask 255.255.255.192 gw xxx eth0

    iface eth0 inet6 static
      address xxx
      netmask xxx
      gateway xxx

    # failover ip
    auto eth0:0
    iface eth0:0 inet static
      address W.X.Y.Z
      netmask 255.255.255.224
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41163/discussion-on-question-by-karussell-dns-issue-with-failover-ip-from-hetzner).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @cherouvim see the answer which explains the reason. I just configure the failover ip on a subset of servers. This solves many of my previously problems already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- As promised, here goes my answer:
- Full disclosure: I'm not working for Hetzner, but worked for different companies in the past and present who used to colocate hardware at Hetzner.
- In case the location inside your profile is correct, and you need support: I'm based in the same city, and could offer a hand, or two.
- For all the people who never dealt with Hetzner: They're filtering network access etc., which means, especially regarding their [failover IPs](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Failover/en#Failover) (IPs which are usable on different machines to provide some sort of high availability), that they're sending traffic directed to a specific IP to a specific MAC.
- If one wants to change the target (the machine) the traffic is directed to, one has to sent a `POST` request to an [API](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Robot_Webservice/en) which is served via `HTTPS`. The API then validates authentication (which is a username and a corresponding password) and the request, and, if valid, propagates this new config to various routers in the network. This technique is similar to the one used by OVH, a big provider based in France.
- Caveat: Albeit people use these IPs to provide some sort of high availability (as written) for their machines / services, the propagation of the new routing config takes some time, sometimes up to ~ 60 seconds. This means, for example, if using some sort of automatic failover, that if a machine to which the traffic currently gets routed to, goes down, for a certain amount of time, which people will notice, the traffic just gets dropped, because the machine is down, up until the point in time when the new routing config is in place.
- So far for the introduction, let's have a look at your specific problem:
- As pointed out in the comments / chat, using `auto eth0:0`, will set up your failover IP at the interface `eth0:0`, as soon as the network gets started, normally at boot time. You've got two machines, with the same configuration, so this leads to the situation, that the same IP is active on two different machines (which isn't a no-go, but leads to the situation you're currently dealing with). Just a note: The syntax you're using, aliasing the same interface multiple times, is [deprecated](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface) (but still working). The "new way" is described inside the Debian wiki (this link) as well, which just assigns multiple IPs to *one* interface.
- So: You've got the IP assigned locally to both machines at the same time. `curl` inside your test case does the following: It resolves the given domain name to an IP, and then tries to connect to this IP at port 443. Because this IP is in any case assigned locally and therefore reachable, the packets never get send out to the network. If `nginx` (like in your test case) is not running locally at this time, you're just getting connection refused, which is totally fine and valid: "The IP is local, so lets send the traffic there". It will never send the packets to some router, which *maybe* has the information: "The traffic directed to this IP should go to this machine".
- Now...actually I'm not entirely sure what you're after. Do you only want to understand whats happening? If so, I've tried to described this. Do you want do find / implement a way, which "solves" this situation? If the later, here are some thoughts:
- Solution 1: Remove the directive `auto eth0:0` (but leave the rest of the configuration of `eth0:0` in place) from `/etc/network/interfaces`. Doing this, will *not* assign the IP to the machine. Doing this would be your task (a task of a script), which does `ifup eth0:0` (and, again *maybe*, speaks to the API to ensure the traffic gets routed to the correct machine).
- Solution 2, aka "automate all the things": Don't do manual failover, but implement a system which does this automatically, via heartbeats (to check the health) between both machines: Multiple solutions exist for this, for example the [Virtual Router Redundancy Protocol](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Router_Redundancy_Protocol) and (full disclosure: my personal favorite, I'm using this since years in production for tasks like this): [corosync and pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/), which is the de facto standard to set up clusters providing high availability under Linux. (Also, have a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/q/733177/269679).) If you want to try out the later way, the fine folks of Kumina developed (and published) a [resource agent](https://blog.kumina.nl/2011/02/hetzner-failover-ip-ocf-script/) some years ago for exactly dealing with this situation at Hetzner. The resource agent takes care of updating the routing information via speaking to the API.
- To come to an end (for now): I'm not entirely sure what you're after. I've tried to described the root cause of the problem you're facing right now. Additionally, I've tried to present some thoughts for possible solutions. In case I didn't got what you're trying to do, there are things which are left unclear or you've got additional questions: Please give feedback, I'm glad to help (or at least try to).
- (Besides: Could you please move your configs etc. into your post, to keep all the stuff in one place, so this question could be of help in the future to other people?)

Comment: Would it be possible via policy based routing on servers A and B that whenever `W.X.Y.Z` is pinged from within A or B that this shouldn't simply point to self and that the parent gateway should provide the answer?

Comment: @cherouvim I've to admit, I don't know if this is possible. I think this would require more in-depth knowledge of the Linux TCP/IP stack etc. I'm not sure if it's possible to set up rules like this for IPs which are locally reachable. I could imagine doing this via some `iptables` magic would work, but I never researched this. Anyway I think one has to set up scripts / software etc. for monitoring health etc. and to speak to the API in case of failures, so I'm not sure if such a way would gain that much.

Answer (score 1):

We faced the exact same issue of self-looping like @gf_ mentioned.

Following library worked flawlessly to achieve the same.

https://github.com/mrkamel/heartbeat

You can add and delete the floating IP to a remote node by using the hooks/after and hooks/before feature of the above library.

Example **hooks/before/sendmail** script that sends a slack notifcation and adds floating ip to the machine its switching to.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo " Switching to failover ip $1 from $2 to $3" | slacktee.sh  

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $3 'ip addr add '"$1"'/32 dev `route | grep "^default" | grep -o "[^ ]*$"`'
```

Example **hooks/after/sendmail** script that sends a slack notifcation and deletes floating ip that it moved away from

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $2 'ip addr del '"$1"'/32 dev `route | grep "^default" | grep -o "[^ ]*$"`'

echo " Switch success for failover ip $1 from $2 to $3"| slacktee.sh
```

Note: 
1. The machine where you are running the heartbeat and the machines where floating IPs are assigned should have password less login using ssh key exchange at first place (Check id_rsa sharing).
2. slacktee.sh library is used to send slack notifications simply.